# Is there an analytical solution for a single unknown in this summation?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following relation:

$$ y = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{f_i}{1+e^{g_i + \alpha}},$$

where $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $y,\alpha, f_i,g_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_i=1$. Furthermore, all parameters are known, except for $\alpha$.

Is there an analytical solution for the unknown $\alpha$.

Comment: That looks like a fermionic average of $f_i$, with energies $E_i=g_i \times k_{\mathrm B}T$ and chemical potential $\mu=\alpha\times k_{\mathrm B}T$. In these situations, physicists usually take a low temperature approximation, called [Sommerfeld expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_expansion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rational function of $x = e^\alpha$.  Finding $x$ (and therefore $\alpha$) will require solving a polynomial equation of degree $N$.  There is
no closed form solution, unless you count "RootOf" as closed-form.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I suppose I'll throw in a Newton-Raphson algorithm to get a satisfactory result. Or would you advise a different, maybe better and/or simpler approach?